# PHP SOAP - adding TicketHeader

Tags: php, api, soap

Using SOAP API in PHP. I need to add my ticket as TicketHeader. The request should be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <TicketHeader xmlns="http://www.webcrm.com/">
      <Guid>***MY_TICKET_ID***</Guid>
    </TicketHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <ReturnAllUsers xmlns="http://www.webcrm.com/" />
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I currently have this code - I can't get the ticket applied, and I don't know what the NAMESPACE is. I know the headerlines are incorrect, but the start where the ticket is collected works.

```
$wsdlUrl = 'https://webcrmapi5.b2bsys.net/WebCrmApi.asmx?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 1));         
$res = $client->Authenticate(array('dbnCode' => $wcrm_dbncode, 'userName' => $wcrm_user, 'password' => $wcrm_pw));
$ticket = $client->__getLastResponse();

$header = new SoapHeader("http://www.webcrm.com/", "TicketHeader", $ticket, false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$users = $client->ReturnAllUsers()->ReturnAllUsersResult;

print_r($users);
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitively use a WSDL to php generator such as the PackageGenerator project as the generated classes associated to the request you must send contain the method to easily set the SoapHeader using a generated class that matches the data to set.

In addition it eases you the request construction, the request sending and finally the response handling.

You can have an example in the auto generated PHP SDK for PayPal Soap API in the [Set service class](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackagePayPal/blob/develop/src/ServiceType/Set.php#L23).